# SVG texture blurried from canvas in three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, three.js

im trying to use an SVG as texture over a model with UV mapping, the thing is that is getting very blurried, im taking the texture from a 2D canvas and it looks ok but over the model it looks so bad, screenshot attached, any idea?

The purpose to use an SVG is because in that way i can manipulate the color properties dinamically, so use a JPG or PNG is not an option

[image]

EDIT:Live version here -> test.fasterwear.com

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. It is hard to help debug code we can't see.

Comment: Edited and live version added, thanks

Comment: That's not very helpful, because (a) that's not a **minimal** example. Please create a Stack Overflow code snippet, fiddle, codepen etc, and (b) If you fix that external site, this question won't be of any help to future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem. Have a look at the values returned by

```
var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: does anyone bother explaining the solution with more detail? I'm facing the exact same problem and I see neither code nor explanations here. thanks